# How do I cross-compile node.js for ARM architecture? GCC does not report the FP ABI compiled for

Tags: arm, cross-compilation, node.js

### Environment

- TARGET Single board computer: FriendlyARM mini210s
- TARGET Linux : 3.0.8 armv7l
- Cross compiling on vagrant box Ubuntu Precise64

## Cross-compiling with GCC 4.5.1

- `arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc` (ctng-1.8.1-FA) 4.5.1

### `arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc --verbose`

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/libexec/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.5.1/lto-wrapper
Target: arm-none-linux-gnueabi
Configured with: /work/toolchain/build/src/gcc-4.5.1/configure --build=i686-build_pc-linux-gnu --host=i686-build_pc-linux-gnu --target=arm-none-linux-gnueabi --prefix=/opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1 --with-sysroot=/opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/sys-root --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-multilib --with-cpu=arm1176jzf-s --with-tune=arm1176jzf-s --with-fpu=vfp --with-float=softfp --with-pkgversion=ctng-1.8.1-FA --with-bugurl=http://www.arm9.net/ --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libmudflap --with-host-libstdcxx='-static-libgcc -Wl,-Bstatic,-lstdc++,-Bdynamic -lm' --with-gmp=/work/toolchain/build/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/build/static --with-mpfr=/work/toolchain/build/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/build/static --with-ppl=/work/toolchain/build/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/build/static --with-cloog=/work/toolchain/build/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/build/static --with-mpc=/work/toolchain/build/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/build/static --with-libelf=/work/toolchain/build/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/build/static --enable-threads=posix --with-local-prefix=/opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/sys-root --disable-nls --enable-symvers=gnu --enable-c99 --enable-long-long
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.5.1 (ctng-1.8.1-FA)
```

I am getting an error and the message "Your version of GCC does not report the FP ABI compiled for."

Hereafter the steps I went through:

### Get node.js

```
wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.35/node-v0.10.35.tar.gz 
tar xzvf node-v0.10.35.tar.gz 
cd node-v0.10.35/
```

### Setting environment

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/bin
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/lib/pkgconfig 
export CC=/opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc
export CXX=/opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++
export AR=/opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ar
export RANLIB=/opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ranlib
export LINK="${CXX}"
export CCFLAGS="-march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a8 -mfpu=vfp -mfloat-abi=hard -DUSE_EABI_HARDFLOAT"
export CXXFLAGS="-march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a8 -mfpu=vfp -mfloat-abi=hard -DUSE_EABI_HARDFLOAT"
export OPENSSL_armcap=7
export GYPFLAGS="-Darmeabi=hard -Dv8_use_arm_eabi_hardfloat=true -Dv8_can_use_vfp3_instructions=true -Dv8_can_use_vfp2_instructions=true -Darm7=1"
export VFP3=on
export VFP2=on
export PREFIX_DIR=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi
```

#### Configure

```
vagrant@vagrant:~/node-v0.10.35$ ./configure --without-snapshot --without-ssl --dest-cpu=arm --dest-os=linux --with-arm-float-abi=hard --prefix="${PREFIX_DIR}"

 { 'target_defaults': { 'cflags': [],
                       'default_configuration': 'Release',
                       'defines': [],
                       'include_dirs': [],
                       'libraries': []},
  'variables': { 'arm_fpu': 'vfpv2',
                 'arm_neon': 0,
                 'armv7': 0,
                 'clang': 0,
                 'gcc_version': 45,
                 'host_arch': 'arm',
                 'node_install_npm': 'true',
                 'node_prefix': '/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi',
                 'node_shared_cares': 'false',
                 'node_shared_http_parser': 'false',
                 'node_shared_libuv': 'false',
                 'node_shared_openssl': 'false',
                 'node_shared_v8': 'false',
                 'node_shared_zlib': 'false',
                 'node_tag': '',
                 'node_unsafe_optimizations': 0,
                 'node_use_dtrace': 'false',
                 'node_use_etw': 'false',
                 'node_use_openssl': 'false',
                 'node_use_perfctr': 'false',
                 'node_use_systemtap': 'false',
                 'openssl_no_asm': 0,
                 'python': '/usr/bin/python',
                 'target_arch': 'arm',
                 'v8_enable_gdbjit': 0,
                 'v8_no_strict_aliasing': 1,
                 'v8_use_arm_eabi_hardfloat': 'true',
                 'v8_use_snapshot': 'false',
                 'want_separate_host_toolset': 0}}
creating  ./config.gypi
creating  ./config.mk
```

### The Issue

After running `make` I am getting the following message:

#### Your version of GCC does not report the FP ABI compiled for.

```
vagrant@vagrant:~/node-v0.10.35$ make -j 2
make -C out BUILDTYPE=Release V=1
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/vagrant/node-v0.10.35/out'
  /opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ '-DENABLE_DEBUGGER_SUPPORT' '-DENABLE_EXTRA_CHECKS' '-DV8_TARGET_ARCH_ARM' '-DUSE_EABI_HARDFLOAT=1' '-DCAN_USE_VFP2_INSTRUCTIONS' -I../deps/v8/src  -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -mfloat-abi=hard -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-tree-vrp -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -MMD -MF /home/vagrant/node-v0.10.35/out/Release/.deps//home/vagrant/node-v0.10.35/out/Release/obj.target/v8_base/deps/v8/src/platform-linux.o.d.raw -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a8 -mfpu=vfp -mfloat-abi=hard -DUSE_EABI_HARDFLOAT -c -o /home/vagrant/node-v0.10.35/out/Release/obj.target/v8_base/deps/v8/src/platform-linux.o ../deps/v8/src/platform-linux.cc
  /opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ '-DENABLE_DEBUGGER_SUPPORT' '-DENABLE_EXTRA_CHECKS' '-DV8_TARGET_ARCH_ARM' '-DUSE_EABI_HARDFLOAT=1' '-DCAN_USE_VFP2_INSTRUCTIONS' -I../deps/v8/src  -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -mfloat-abi=hard -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-tree-vrp -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -MMD -MF /home/vagrant/node-v0.10.35/out/Release/.deps//home/vagrant/node-v0.10.35/out/Release/obj.target/v8_base/deps/v8/src/platform-posix.o.d.raw -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a8 -mfpu=vfp -mfloat-abi=hard -DUSE_EABI_HARDFLOAT -c -o /home/vagrant/node-v0.10.35/out/Release/obj.target/v8_base/deps/v8/src/platform-posix.o ../deps/v8/src/platform-posix.cc
../deps/v8/src/platform-linux.cc:223:2: error: #error "Your version of GCC does not report the FP ABI compiled for." "Please report it on this issue" "http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=2140"
../deps/v8/src/platform-linux.cc: In static member function 'static bool v8::internal::OS::ArmUsingHardFloat()':
../deps/v8/src/platform-linux.cc:230:1: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void
make[1]: *** [/home/vagrant/node-v0.10.35/out/Release/obj.target/v8_base/deps/v8/src/platform-linux.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
../deps/v8/src/platform-posix.cc: In static member function 'static int v8::internal::OS::VSNPrintF(v8::internal::Vector<char>, const char*, va_list)':
../deps/v8/src/platform-posix.cc:338:5: note: the mangling of 'va_list' has changed in GCC 4.4
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/vagrant/node-v0.10.35/out'
make: *** [node] Error 2
```

The issue seems to be related to `hard abi` vs `soft abi` ... and I don't know what difference it makes.

What is `hard abi`? and do I need it for `node.js` cross-compillation?

## UPDATE Cross-compiling with GCC 4.6.3

- `arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++` (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3

#### Env

```
export CC=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
export CXX=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
export AR=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-ar
export RANLIB=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-ranlib
```

I run the same `configure` command and then `make` and I am getting a different error this time:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: warning: ld-linux.so.3, needed by /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.6/libstdc++.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/vagrant/node-v0.10.35/out/Release/obj.target/node/src/node.o: In function `node::Init(int, char**)':
node.cc:(.text+0x2be0): undefined reference to `node::SSL2_ENABLE'
node.cc:(.text+0x2c00): undefined reference to `node::SSL3_ENABLE'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [/home/vagrant/node-v0.10.35/out/Release/node] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/vagrant/node-v0.10.35/out'
make: *** [node] Error 2
```

Comment: What is your gcc version? Run `gcc --version`. Even better, what is the output of `gcc --verbose`?

Comment: Updated question with the details you asked for.

Comment: I believe the output is fine. What if you change the `configure` options to `--with-arm-float-abi=soft` or `--with-arm-float-abi=softfp`? Also, could you point out where you downloaded this gcc toolchain?

Comment: Looks like I may need to look for a more recent version of GCC that's all

Comment: Yes I tried with the `soft` param earlier today, but I may not have done it as you specified. The toolchain was download from the FriendlyARM website. ftp.friendlyarm.net

Comment: I downloaded the 4.4.3 version from their website but couldn't compile it too. However, I got different error messages. But I still recommend you to try with the `soft` option. Make sure to do a `make clean` before re-compiling.

Comment: I got GCC 4.5.1 from ftp://ftp.friendlyarm.net/mini210/Mini210s-20120913.iso Credentials to access the FTP server are at the bottom of this [page](http://www.friendlyarm.net/downloads#download). I am now trying the `soft` option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Using GCC 4.5.1 - FAIL

`arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc` (ctng-1.8.1-FA) 4.5.1 does not report the FP ABI compiled for, as mentioned in the error message. [Read more about the issue](https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=2140)

I have tried to use `./configure --with-arm-float-abi=softpf` and `soft` as suggested by Robert or Thiago. I didn't follow this path all the way.

#### Environment

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/bin
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/lib/pkgconfig 
export CC=/opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc
export CXX=/opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++
export AR=/opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ar
export RANLIB=/opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ranlib
export LINK="${CXX}"
export CCFLAGS="-march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a8 -mfpu=vfp -mfloat-abi=soft "
export CXXFLAGS="-march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a8 -mfpu=vfp -mfloat-abi=soft "
export OPENSSL_armcap=7
export GYPFLAGS="-Darmeabi=soft -Dv8_use_arm_eabi_hardfloat=false -Dv8_can_use_vfp3_instructions=true -Dv8_can_use_vfp2_instructions=true -Darm7=1"
export VFP3=on
export VFP2=on
export PREFIX_DIR=/usr
```

#### Configure

```
  ./configure --without-snapshot --dest-cpu=arm --dest-os=linux --with-arm-float-abi=soft --prefix="${PREFIX_DIR}"
```

#### "Your version of GCC does not report the FP ABI compiled for" error

```
vagrant@vagrant:~/node-v0.10.35$ make
make -C out BUILDTYPE=Release V=1
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/vagrant/node-v0.10.35/out'
  /opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ '-DENABLE_DEBUGGER_SUPPORT' '-DENABLE_EXTRA_CHECKS' '-DV8_TARGET_ARCH_ARM' '-DUSE_EABI_HARDFLOAT=0' -I../deps/v8/src  -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-tree-vrp -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -MMD -MF /home/vagrant/node-v0.10.35/out/Release/.deps//home/vagrant/node-v0.10.35/out/Release/obj.target/v8_base/deps/v8/src/platform-linux.o.d.raw -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a8 -mfpu=vfp -mfloat-abi=soft  -c -o /home/vagrant/node-v0.10.35/out/Release/obj.target/v8_base/deps/v8/src/platform-linux.o ../deps/v8/src/platform-linux.cc
../deps/v8/src/platform-linux.cc:223:2: error: #error "Your version of GCC does not report the FP ABI compiled for." "Please report it on this issue" "http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=2140"
../deps/v8/src/platform-linux.cc: In static member function 'static bool v8::internal::OS::ArmUsingHardFloat()':
../deps/v8/src/platform-linux.cc:230:1: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void
make[1]: *** [/home/vagrant/node-v0.10.35/out/Release/obj.target/v8_base/deps/v8/src/platform-linux.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/vagrant/node-v0.10.35/out'
make: *** [node] Error 2
```

## Using GCC 4.6.3 - CROSS-COMPILATION PASS

Removed the `--without-ssl` in my configure command and it compiled well (no errors) with `arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++` (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3

```
vagrant@vagrant:~/node-v0.10.35$ ./configure --without-snapshot --dest-cpu=arm --dest-os=linux --with-arm-float-abi=hard --prefix="${PREFIX_DIR}"
```

It compiles and runs well on the target!

However `npm` shows errors posted question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177764/npm-on-arm-return-typeerror-bad-argument)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are telling it you want the vector floating point unit (`-mfpu=vfp`), but that GCC should generate hard floating point instructions (`-mfloat-abi=hard -DUSE_EABI_HARDFLOAT`).

From [GCC ARM options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.6/gcc/ARM-Options.html):

> Using -mfloat-abi=hard with VFP coprocessors is not supported. Use
>   -mfloat-abi=softfp with the appropriate -mfpu option to allow the compiler to generate code that makes use of the hardware
>   floating-point capabilities for these CPUs.

I use the following options with the TI AM3505 (Cortex A8 + FPU) and it compiles ok (GCC 4.8.2):

`-march=armv7-a -mthumb-interwork -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=neon -mtune=cortex-a8`

Comment: this helped understanding better the issue, but I still wasn't able to compile. I am getting the same message. Let me try harder and will let you know.

Comment: I would try dropping back to just `-march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp` for `CCFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS`. My build system (yocto) doesn't even generate `GYPFLAGS` so I'm not sure what to suggest there; they looks like v8 optimizations and you can probably just leave them out entirely. (What is generating the environment variables?)

Comment: I guess you are past the fp issue (looks like `./configure --with-arm-float-abi=softpf` is the best way to fix that.) and are having problems with your cross-compile sysroot. When you cross compile you have to tell the linker where your shared libraries are. What build system are you using?

Comment: I am building on `Precise64` and the target is `Linux 3.0.8 armv7l`. I have tried your suggestion but no success so far (same error message **GCC does not report the FP ABI**). I'd really like to have it work with `GCC 4.5.1`, because it is the Toolchain I have used to compile other utilities. Besides the `node` executable I was able to produce using `GCC 4.6` doesn't run on my target (yet another issue)