# npm on ARM return TypeError: Bad argument

Tags: arm, node.js, npm

### Env

- Cross-compiled `node.js` for ARM [read more...](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/176623/how-do-i-cross-compile-node-js-for-arm-architecture-gcc-does-not-report-the-fp/177706#177706)
- Installed on target FriendlyARM `mini210s` running bare Linux 3.0.8 armv7l

#### On target

`node.js` seems to function properly. I tried a simple hello word example.

```
# node -v    
v0.10.35
```

However the `npm` throws me an error

```
# npm -v

buffer.js:74
      return this.base64Slice(start, end);
                  ^
TypeError: Bad argument.
    at SlowBuffer.toString (buffer.js:74:19)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:438:19
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:474:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:24:11
```

Any leads are welcome.